# Oracle SQL REGEXP_SUBSTR() and SUBSTR() issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to modify a query that I have created to bring back only records that DO NOT start with the string 'PO:'

The records I want are all different in the way they start but none of the ones I want start with 'PO:'. Some may start with numbers or some may start with other words.

I know by using REGEXP_SUBSTR() or just SUBSTR() I can pull back data based solely on numbers or letters but how do I **Not include** certain words/strings.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `NOT`

ex : `yourcolumn not like 'PO%'`

It accepts all values wich does not begin by 'PO'

Comment: I knew I was overthinking it. This worked perfectly Thank you!